# CentOS Postfix changing mail server

Tags: centos, configuration, postfix

I've been using Postfix on my CentOS 6 Server on it's default install settings but I would like to configure it to use the mail server from my existing email.

I altered the /etc/postfix/main.cf file by adding

```
relayhost = [mail.mywebsite.com]:993
```

Then at the bottom I added

```
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
```

Then in /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd I added

```
[mail.mywebsite.com]:993    my_uname:my_pword
```

I gave that file 600 permissions, then ran

```
# postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
```

and finally I restarted postfix. After these changes it no longer works as when I try to send an email I am getting the following error

```
-Queue ID- --Size-- ----Arrival Time---- -Sender/Recipient-------
2FF29F0F        355 Thu Jun  4 11:56:24  root@centos6.localdomain
(lost connection with mail.mywebsite.com[192.185.2.93] while receiving the
initial server greeting)
                                         receiver@companyemail.com

-- 0 Kbytes in 1 Request
```

Is there something that I did wrong in setting this up?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve here. Port 993 is for IMAP but postfix is an SMTP server. Do you want to *forward* incoming messages on your CentOS postfix service to your company's internal mail server? Or do you want to use postfix to *read* messages from your company's mail server?

Comment: I'm hoping to use it as a relay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postfix is an SMTP server, but port 993 is used for IMAPS. Try using 25, 465 or 587 instead, depending on what mail.mywebsite.com supports.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I have a second option for my relay I will try that and leave it's port as default and I'll let you know

Comment: worked perfectly, I didn't realise the IMAP would be an issue, thanks a bunch man